# How to make images fade, visible when i'm scrolling and the action should be reapeat

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm using the below js script and css for make all images visibility hidden and while scrolling it will show slowly. Its working fine but my question is its working once when the page was loaded. How can I make the image fade and come not only once when the page was loaded, the action must be repeat.

```js
function showImages(el) {
  var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
  $(el).each(function() {
    var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 200 > thisPos) {
      $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  showImages('.star');
});
```

```css
.star {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: animat_show 0.8s;
  animation: animat_show 0.8s;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animat_show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"/>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Other  test</p>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant code

Comment: Hi code had been updated. Its working fine but its comes only once after loading but I want this action while scroll down and up.

Comment: Perhaps preload image and put the script before the </body> tag

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showImages(el) {
  var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
  $(el).each(function() {
    var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 200 > thisPos) {
      $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
    }else{
      $(this).removeClass("fadeIn");
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  showImages('.star');
});
```

```css
.star {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) .25s;
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: animat_show 0.8s;
  animation: animat_show 0.8s;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animat_show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"/>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<img class="star" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Other  test</p>
```

Comment: @Saravanan_Shankar Ok . Please feel free to get back for any doubts and don't forget to mark as correct.